# How to setup DataGrip connect Cloud SQL with SSL mode through Tunnel using DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, ssl, datagrip

I am a newbie for Cloud SQL and Cloud Security. So now I already use Cloud SQL and connect to the database with Compute Engine. I use it as a proxy server and use for remote connect from my local machine.

And then I need to use SSL connection try to create new client certificates and it was OK if I connect from my proxy server.

But not work when I try to connect from the local machine using DataGrip. I got an error message.

> Connection to postgres@database-server failed.
>   [08006] Could not open SSL root certificate file /home/user/.postgresql/root.crt.

Comment: What version of DataGrip do you use?

Comment: I use version 2019.1 and I use all private key files that generate from Google Cloud SQL and use at SSL tab and include ssh config for connecting to the proxy server.

Comment: Try to update to the latest DataGrip version. We reworked SSL subsystem significantly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by a change in the Postgres JDBC driver after version 42.2.2. Subsequent versions treat *ssl=true* to also be *sslmode=verify-ca* while also introducing a change that causes the default SSLFactory to not recognize the JRE *cacerts*.

To resolve this, either revert to driver 42.2.2 or set the sslfactory to *org.postgresql.ssl.DefaultJavaSSLFactory*

There is also a GitHub issue
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1307

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, to work properly using SSL you need to configure DataGrip in the following way.

1. Go to SSH/SSL tab
2. Enable SSL and provide paths to CA cert, client cert & client private key
3. Go to Advanced tab
4. Find `sslmode` property and set desired verification level, e.g. verify-ca
5. Find `sslrootcert` property and provide path to your `ca.cert`

Furthermore, did you put your `root.crt` to `/home/user/.postgresql/root.crt`?

Also, if to refer to https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl use the following parameters:

`sslmode=verify-ca`

`sslrootcert=/path/to/your/server-ca.pem`

`ca file=/path/to/your/server-ca.pem`

`client certificate file=/path/to/your/client-cert.pem`

`client key file=/path/to/your/client-key.pem`

Comment: FYI, I try to connect to Cloud SQL through SSH tunnel & SSL. Now It still not working. I try to connect without SSH tunnel using SSL mode still got the same error.

So I was wondering about cert files from Google. Can use it without doing anything?
And what about root.crt?

Actually, It was work before I update the version of DataGrip.
So I try to use other software I got the same error, too.

For the URL you prefer I already tried it. It works from a proxy server.

Comment: After I try to do like you advice me. I got a new error

Connection to postgres@db-server failed.
[08006] SSL error: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message